# C++ fstream not working properly

Tags: c++, fstream

This program is executing without giving any error. But nothing seems to be written or read from test.txt.

Please help me spot the mistake. I feel I have implemented ofstream and ifstream correctly. I am unable to spot what I am missing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

   ofstream fout;
   ifstream fin;
   string s;
   cout<<"Enter a string: ";
   getline(cin,s);

   fout.open("test.txt");
   if(fout.is_open())
   {
      fout<<s;
      fout.close();
   }
   else
   {
      cout<<"Error ";
   }

   fin.open("test.txt");

   if(fout.is_open())
   {
      while(getline(fin,s))
      {
         cout<<"here";
         cout<<s<<endl;
      }
      fout.close();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check where you use `fout` and `fin`.  Add `#include <string>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(fout.is_open()) { // <<< should be fin
    while(getline(fin,s)) {
        cout<<"here";
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }

    fout.close(); // <<< also fin is needed here!
}
```

You're confusing `fin` and `fout` in your code.

See the fixed version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1272b7e54a5ce474) please (note I've just used a predefined string instead of user input):

```
fin.open("test.txt");
if(fin.is_open()) {
    while(getline(fin,s)) {
        cout<<"here";
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```